# groupby and replace certain values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group by id search for a comment and replace all rows associated with the id with the comment that appears under each id.

My current logic was to replace all rows associated with the id with the modal value, but in certain cases the comment is not the mode (nan is)

this is my code:

```
file['name'] = file.groupby('data__id')['name'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))
```

data sample:

```
data__id      name
1              yes
1
2              
2               no
2
```

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here `mode` should return multiple values, so select first by indexing by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df['name'] = df.groupby('data__id')['name'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iat[0]))
print (df)
   data__id name
0         1  yes
1         1  yes
2         2   no
3         2   no
4         2   no
```

If get:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

use `next` with `iter` for return default value if `mode` return empty `Series` because group contains only missing values:

```
print (df)
   data__id name
0         1  yes
1         1  NaN
2         2  NaN
3         2   no
4         2  NaN
5         3  NaN

f = lambda x: x.fillna(next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan))
df['name'] = df.groupby('data__id')['name'].apply(f)
print (df)
   data__id name
0         1  yes
1         1  yes
2         2   no
3         2   no
4         2   no
5         3  NaN
```

Or custom value:

```
f = lambda x: x.fillna(next(iter(x.mode()), 'no match'))
df['name'] = df.groupby('data__id')['name'].apply(f)
print (df)
   data__id      name
0         1       yes
1         1       yes
2         2        no
3         2        no
4         2        no
5         3  no match
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using `transform` rather than `apply`

```
s=df.groupby('data__id')['name'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
df.name.fillna(s,inplace=True)
```